# Pass bearer token in request chain

Tags: node.js, express, request

I'm using Express and I can chain requests together until it comes to trying to pass the bearer token from one api request to the header of another. It must be something really simple, but I can't pass the json response into a req variable.

```
const getAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("HITS GET ACCESS TOKEN")
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    return res.json(body);
  });
  next()
};

const getMgmtToken = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("HITS GET MGMT TOKEN")
  next()
};

app.post("/createUser", getAccessToken, getMgmtToken, (req, res) => {
  return res.send("END");
});
```

I fire up the server and hit the createUser endpoint, which calls getAccessToken and gives me the access token as a response from my api, but I can't do this - it just gives me undefined:

```
const getAccessToken = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("HITS GET ACCESS TOKEN")
  request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    return req.token = body;
  });
  next()
};

const getMgmtToken = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("HITS GET MGMT TOKEN", req.token )
  next()
};
```

How do I pass the bearer token to the next middleware?

Comment: `request` is async? If so, you need to wait to be resolved before you continue the chain.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have any effect - I tried const getAccessToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("HITS GET ACCESS TOKEN")
  const token = await request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    return  res.json(body);
  });
  req.token = token
  next()
};